# Erro 404 - Not Found - httpsURLConnection Java

Tags: java, api, http-request

Boa tarde!

Estou tentando realizar uma requisição da API do ReceitaWS mas não estou conseguindo.

A API utilizar o Bearer token como forma de autenticação e apenas a url de requisição com o cnpj em que deseja retornar os dados, estou desenvolvendo um código em java para retornar essas informações mas não estou conseguindo.

Quanto tento fazer pelo postman funciona perfeitamente mas quando tento pelo Java não consigo.

Conseguem me dizer se o meu código está errado:
Classe sendHTTPData

```
    public class sendHTTPData {

    public sendHTTPData() {
    }
    
    public String call(String urlpath) throws Exception{
        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
        String authString = "Bearer {authToken}";
        
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlpath);
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authString);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                String response = null;
                while((response = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(response + "\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            }else {
                System.out.println("responsecode - "+connection.getResponseCode());
                System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode() + " - " +connection.getResponseMessage());
                System.out.println(connection.getErrorStream());
                
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro: "+e.toString());
            return null;
        } finally {
            if(connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Classe EnviaCNPJ

```
public class EnviaCNPJ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/06099229000101/days/20";
        
        try {
            sendHTTPData invoker = new sendHTTPData();
            String doc = invoker.call(url);
            
            System.out.println(doc);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Boa tarde, vou te sugerir uma solução mais "elegante", mais fácil que eu uso aqui usando RestTemplate.

```
    public PessoaConsulta consulta(String cnpj) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        PessoaConsulta pessoa = restTemplate.getForObject(
                "https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/" +cnpj, PessoaConsulta.class);
        return pessoa;
    }
```

E a classe Pessoa...

```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PessoaConsulta {

    private String nome;
    private String status;
    private String message;
    private String cnpj;
    private String tipo;
    private String abertura;
    private String fantasia;
    private String natureza_juridica;
    private String logradouro;
    private String numero;
    private String complemento;
    private String cep;
    private String bairro;
    private String municipio;
    private String uf;
    private String email;
    private String telefone;
    private String situacao;
    private String data_situacao;
    private String motivo_situacao;
    private String situacao_especial;
    private String data_situacao_especial;
    private String capital_social;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String getSituacao() {
        return situacao;
    }

    public void setSituacao(String situacao) {
        this.situacao = situacao;
    }

    public String getData_situacao() {
        return data_situacao;
    }

    public void setData_situacao(String data_situacao) {
        this.data_situacao = data_situacao;
    }

    public String getMotivo_situacao() {
        return motivo_situacao;
    }

    public void setMotivo_situacao(String motivo_situacao) {
        this.motivo_situacao = motivo_situacao;
    }

    public String getSituacao_especial() {
        return situacao_especial;
    }

    public void setSituacao_especial(String situacao_especial) {
        this.situacao_especial = situacao_especial;
    }

    public String getData_situacao_especial() {
        return data_situacao_especial;
    }

    public void setData_situacao_especial(String data_situacao_especial) {
        this.data_situacao_especial = data_situacao_especial;
    }

    public String getCapital_social() {
        return capital_social;
    }

    public void setCapital_social(String capital_social) {
        this.capital_social = capital_social;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PessoaConsulta{" + "nome=" + nome + ", status=" + status + ", message=" + message + ", cnpj=" + cnpj + ", tipo=" + tipo + ", abertura=" + abertura + ", fantasia=" + fantasia + ", natureza_juridica=" + natureza_juridica + ", logradouro=" + logradouro + ", numero=" + numero + ", complemento=" + complemento + ", cep=" + cep + ", bairro=" + bairro + ", municipio=" + municipio + ", uf=" + uf + ", email=" + email + ", telefone=" + telefone + ", situacao=" + situacao + ", data_situacao=" + data_situacao + ", motivo_situacao=" + motivo_situacao + ", situacao_especial=" + situacao_especial + ", data_situacao_especial=" + data_situacao_especial + ", capital_social=" + capital_social + '}';
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getCnpj() {
        return cnpj;
    }

    public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getAbertura() {
        return abertura;
    }

    public void setAbertura(String abertura) {
        this.abertura = abertura;
    }

    public String getFantasia() {
        return fantasia;
    }

    public void setFantasia(String fantasia) {
        this.fantasia = fantasia;
    }

    public String getNatureza_juridica() {
        return natureza_juridica;
    }

    public void setNatureza_juridica(String natureza_juridica) {
        this.natureza_juridica = natureza_juridica;
    }

    public String getLogradouro() {
        return logradouro;
    }

    public void setLogradouro(String logradouro) {
        this.logradouro = logradouro;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getComplemento() {
        return complemento;
    }

    public void setComplemento(String complemento) {
        this.complemento = complemento;
    }

    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    public void setBairro(String bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    public String getMunicipio() {
        return municipio;
    }

    public void setMunicipio(String municipio) {
        this.municipio = municipio;
    }

    public String getUf() {
        return uf;
    }

    public void setUf(String uf) {
        this.uf = uf;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).